# metodo isset de php cambia los valores?

Tags: php, isset

Estoy usando el metodo `isset()` de php para determinar si la variable esta definida o no, de la siguiente manera:

```
public function __construct() {
            try {
                $this->id = uniqid();
                $this->nombre = htmlentities(strip_tags(isset($_REQUEST['nombre'])), ENT_QUOTES);
                $this->apellido = htmlentities(strip_tags(isset($_REQUEST['apellido'])), ENT_QUOTES);
                $this->fecha_nacimiento = htmlentities(strip_tags(isset($_REQUEST['fecha_nacimiento'])), ENT_QUOTES);
                $this->sexo = htmlentities(strip_tags(isset($_REQUEST['sexo'])), ENT_QUOTES);
                $this->email = htmlentities(strip_tags(isset($_REQUEST['email'])), ENT_QUOTES);
                $this->clave = htmlentities(isset($_REQUEST['clave']), ENT_QUOTES);
                $this->activo = 1;
                $this->foto_perfil = htmlentities(strip_tags(isset($_REQUEST['foto_perfil'])), ENT_QUOTES);
                $this->user = new user();
            } catch (\Throwable $th) {
                http_response_code(500);
            }
        }
```

Y cuando las variables las inserto a la base de datos todo se registra con el numero 1, y cuando le quito el `isset()` recien se inserta en la base de datos con los valores reales que le pase, porque pasa esto?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La función `isset` devuelve `TRUE` o `FALSE` si la variable existe o no, no retorna su valor. Si quieres evaluar la existencia de la variable puedes usar el IF ternario `isset($variable) ? $variable : 'valor por defecto'`, quedando tu código algo así:

```
public function __construct() {
    try {
        $this->id = uniqid();
        $this->nombre = htmlentities(strip_tags(isset($_REQUEST['nombre']) ? $_REQUEST['nombre'] : ''), ENT_QUOTES);
        $this->apellido = htmlentities(strip_tags(isset($_REQUEST['apellido']) ? $_REQUEST['apellido'] : ''), ENT_QUOTES);
        $this->fecha_nacimiento = htmlentities(strip_tags(isset($_REQUEST['fecha_nacimiento']) ? $_REQUEST['fecha_nacimiento'] : ''), ENT_QUOTES);
        $this->sexo = htmlentities(strip_tags(isset($_REQUEST['sexo']) ? $_REQUEST['sexo'] : ''), ENT_QUOTES);
        $this->email = htmlentities(strip_tags(isset($_REQUEST['email']) ? $_REQUEST['email'] : ''), ENT_QUOTES);
        $this->clave = htmlentities(isset($_REQUEST['clave']) ? $_REQUEST['clave'] : '', ENT_QUOTES);
        $this->activo = 1;
        $this->foto_perfil = htmlentities(strip_tags(isset($_REQUEST['foto_perfil']) ? $_REQUEST['foto_perfil'] : ''), ENT_QUOTES);
        $this->user = new user();
    } catch (\Throwable $th) {
        http_response_code(500);
    }
}
```

Si te preocupa la legibilidad del código puedes implementar en una función todas las acciones que actúan sobre cada una de las variables.

Comment: Te recomiendo que propongas usar, como la opción más optima, el operador [fusión de `null`](https://www.php.net/es/language.operators.comparison). Así queda código más compacto y legible: `$_REQUEST['sexo']) ?? ''`. Nota: Disponible a partir de PHP 7, pero teniendo en cuenta que PHP 5.6 salió de soporte hace más de un año, se debería presuponer en desuso.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que no puedes ocupar `isset()` de manera definitiva para insertarlo a tu base de datos. `isset()` solo te va a servir, como bien dijiste, para saber si la variable está definida o no. Si está definida, devolverá un `TRUE` y si no, devolverá un `NULL`.

Si tú tratas de insertar usando esta función te devolverá un `TRUE` que es equivalente a un `1`, por eso te inserta este valor.

Si vas a insertar los valores, ya no ocupes `isset` porque si no vas a tener este problema que te comento.

Lee más sobre esto [aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php).